# Hover to override next element

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a paragraph. When hovered over, it should overclip the text below it

The problem is the H1 text moves its position.

Only the words "HOVER ABOVE PARAGRAPH" should be hidden.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
    display: block;
    margin: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative; /* So position absolute stays in this box */
}

.mouseover-me {
    display: block; /* <a> tag has no defaults */
    height: 55px;
    max-height: 55px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    z-index: 20;
}

.mouseover-me:hover{
    background-color: lightgrey;
    z-index: 20;
    position: absolute;
    max-height: none;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <a class="mouseover-me">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel lacus est. Ut vulputate venenatis mauris porta ornare. Nunc vehicula dapibus sem eget maximus. Nunc vehicula dapibus sem eget maximus. Nunc vehicula dapibus sem eget maximus.</a>
    <h1 class="override-me">HOVER ABOVE PARAGRAPH TO HIDE THIS TEXT PARTIALLY, BUT KEEP THIS H1 TEXT IN THE SAME POSITION</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make two (2) changes:

- `position: absolute` needs to be set on `.mouseover-me` all the time, not just on hover
- you need to reserve space to avoid the initial overlap (`.override-me { padding-top: 55px; }` achieves this)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  display: block;
  margin: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative; /* So position absolute stays in this box */
}
.mouseover-me {
  display: block; /* <a> tag has no defaults */
  height: 55px;
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 55px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  z-index: 20;
}
.mouseover-me:hover{
  background-color: lightgrey;
  z-index: 20;
  max-height: none;
  height: auto;
}
.override-me { padding-top: 55px; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a class="mouseover-me">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel lacus est. Ut vulputate venenatis mauris porta ornare. Nunc vehicula dapibus sem eget maximus. Nunc vehicula dapibus sem eget maximus. Nunc vehicula dapibus sem eget maximus.</a>
  <h1 class="override-me">HOVER ABOVE PARAGRAPH TO HIDE THIS TEXT PARTIALLY, BUT KEEP THIS H1 TEXT IN THE SAME POSITION</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Are there alternative solutions? The site I was inspecting when trying to replicate this only had position absolute on hover though.